# Saber o tamanho de cada elemento de uma list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Supondo que eu tenha uma `List<byte[]> Imagens;` e eu queira saber se algum elemento dessa lista tem mais de 1 mega, eu conseguiria fazer isso via `foreach`, verificando item por item:

```
        foreach (var item in Imagens)
            if (item.Length > 1000000)
                throw new ArgumentException(msn);
```

Qual seria a forma de fazer isso?

A lista deve ser inválida se algum dos seu elementos tiver mais de 1MB.

Comment: Jamais deveria lançar uma exceção para isto. E precisaria explicar melhor o critério. Basta 1 estar fora dessa especificação e deve encerrar o algoritmo sempre? E o objeto é um *array* de bytes a quantidade de elementos em essência é o mesmo que a quantidade bytes. `obter o tamanho total da lista em bytes, assim através de uma simples divisão saberia-se se a Lista contem elementos maiores que 1 mega`. É? Por que? Nenhuma imagem, com toda certeza, é menos 1MB?

Comment: Vou modificar a pergunta e deixar mais direto, mas não vou expor aqui em que contexto isso será usado pois acredito que não é o foco, acredito que isso seria mais adequado para CodeReview.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva forneça o contexto da pergunta, pode ajudar a encontrar uma solução melhor para o seu problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só usar o [`Any`.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
if (imagens.Any(x => x.Length > 1_000_000)) //aí escolhe o que fazer
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/FilterByMember.cs).

Mas não lance uma exceção, isso é inadequado. Controle de fluxo não pode ser feito com um mecanismo de situações excepcionais ou erros de programação (que não devem ser capturadas porque nada pode ser feito neste caso). Se a pergunta tivesse mais contexto eu daria uma solução mais completa e adequada.

Eu usei 1.000.000, mas isso não é o mesmo que 1MB que seria 1.048.576.

Comment: Eu não sabia que essa sintaxe (`1_000_000`) era possível. Qual é a diferença dela para `1000000`? E pq você diz que não o mesmo que 1MB? Essa lista vai receber imagens binarizadas e por regras do negocio não podem ter mais de um mega. Cada elemento da lista corresponde a uma imagem.

Comment: Sobre lançar a exceção, um pouco do contexto. Esse código faz parte da validação de uma propriedade de um Model onde é feita apenas a verificação. Tratar o fluxo nesse caso é responsabilidade de outra camada e não do Model. Por isso a escolha de lançar a exceção, para que quem for trabalhar a outra camada faça o tratamento e determine o fluxo necessário.

Comment: Supondo que cada item da lista tem exatos 1Mb cada um, uma lista com 10 elementos teria em tese 10Mb. Por isso antes eu buscava uma forma de obter o tamanho da lista e não de cada elemento, assim eu poderia fazer algo como `if(imagens.ByteSize / imagens.Count != 1000000)`, obviamente que esse exemplo trata-se de um pseudo código.

Comment: É possível desde C# 7, é só pra ficar mais legível. Cada Kbyte tem 1024 bytes, e 1MB tem 1024 * 1024 bytes. Nunca use exceção pra validação. Tá cheio de pergunta sobre o assunto aqui. Suposições não servem pra computar nada, só certezas.